# Google Ads discrepancies on different aggregates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api

We have a BigQuery data transfer of GoogleAds data. I came to realization, that I probably do not understand what is in the aggregates.

The discrepancy occurs with "Discovery" campaigns. Here is the query:

```sql
SELECT
    '1. AdStats' as table,
    SUM(Clicks)       AS clicks,
    SUM(Cost)/1000000 AS cost,
    SUM(Impressions)  AS impressions
FROM `project.dataset.p_AdStats_*`
WHERE Date = @date AND CampaignId = @campaign
    UNION ALL
SELECT
    '2. AdBasicStats' as table,
    SUM(Clicks)       AS clicks,
    SUM(Cost)/1000000 AS cost,
    SUM(Impressions)  AS impressions
FROM `project.dataset.p_AdBasicStats_*`
WHERE Date = @date AND CampaignId = @campaign
    UNION ALL
SELECT
    '3. AdGroupStats' as table,
    SUM(Clicks)       AS clicks,
    SUM(Cost)/1000000 AS cost,
    SUM(Impressions)  AS impressions
FROM `project.dataset.p_AdGroupStats_*`
WHERE Date = @date AND CampaignId = @campaign
    UNION ALL
SELECT
    '4. AdGroupBasicStats' as table,
    SUM(Clicks)       AS clicks,
    SUM(Cost)/1000000 AS cost,
    SUM(Impressions)  AS impressions
FROM `project.dataset.p_AdGroupBasicStats_*`
WHERE Date = @date AND CampaignId = @campaign
ORDER BY 1
```

The results come in:

```
table                clicks cost       impressions
1. AdStats           74     2.906935   15582
2. AdBasicStats      74     345.444868 15582
3. AdGroupStats      78     15.786935  15802
4. AdGroupBasicStats 78     358.324868 15802
```

The GoogleAds UI shows 78 clicks, €358.32 and 15802 impressions for campaign report. It matches `AdGroupBasicStats`.

But I need more.. I need math to hold - AdBasicStats should have the same data, but in more granular detail (on Ad level). But it does not. Also, this is just killing me:

```
345.444868 + 15.786935 - 2.906935 = 358.324868 ?!?!
```

What the actual f...? I've tested multiple days, different campaigns. The math is there.
Can someone explain me what does those aggregates have? Point me to any resource describing the data in the tables, please.

Couple of notes:

1. I suspect that data from `AdStats` is already in both `AdBasicStats` and `AdGroupStats`. Thus the minus in equation. But what does that data stand for? How can I identify such data in other aggregates?
2. Backfill is not the culprit, I've refreshed data multiple times in historical periods.
3. Interestingly enough, this behaviour only occurs with "Discovery" campaigns. Other types, e.g. "Display", seems not to have this discrepancy.
4. I've tried to contact Google Ads support, but they directed me to the GCP support instead, which we don't have available for our account.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Attribution reports ( such as AdStats and AdGroupStats which have 'Click Type') should not be aggregated together because they may double count impressions and clicks. Aggregation of Metrics should be based in BasicStats tables. Discovery campaigns are not reported in single attribution reports which can affect the metrics.

According to google API documentation.
"Warning: Discovery campaigns are not supported in single attribution reports. If you have criteria from Discovery campaigns in your report, then the total metrics can be unexpected."
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting#segmentation